# How to implement Materialized view in PL/SQL using Collections

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I'm new to PL/SQL. I have created one simple materialized view that I have to convert PL/SQL using collections.

Can anyone give me the logic how to achieve this?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW EMP_VW(ENAME,DNAME,JOB,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO)
AS 
    SELECT              IV.EMP_NAME,
                        IV.JOB,
                        IV.SALARY,
                        IV.COMMISSION,
                        IV.DEPARTMENT_NO,
                        IV.DEPARTMENT_NAME
     FROM(  SELECT                  EMP.ENAME       AS  EMP_NAME,
                                    EMP.JOB         AS  JOB,
                                    EMP.SAL         AS  SALARY,
                                    EMP.COMM        AS  COMMISSION,
                                    EMP.DEPTNO      AS  DEPARTMENT_NO,
                                    DEPT.DNAME      AS  DEPARTMENT_NAME
           FROM         SCOTT.EMP INNER JOIN SCOTT.DEPT
           ON           EMP.DEPTNO=DEPT.DEPTNO
           AND          EMP.DEPTNO IN(10,20)
           ORDER        BY  EMP.DEPTNO) IV;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request correctly, this is how you pull a select statement's returned values into a collection.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR my_cur IS
    SELECT              IV.EMP_NAME,
                        IV.JOB,
                        IV.SALARY,
                        IV.COMMISSION,
                        IV.DEPARTMENT_NO,
                        IV.DEPARTMENT_NAME
     FROM(  SELECT                  EMP.ENAME       AS  EMP_NAME,
                                    EMP.JOB         AS  JOB,
                                    EMP.SAL         AS  SALARY,
                                    EMP.COMM        AS  COMMISSION,
                                    EMP.DEPTNO      AS  DEPARTMENT_NO,
                                    DEPT.DNAME      AS  DEPARTMENT_NAME
           FROM         SCOTT.EMP INNER JOIN SCOTT.DEPT
           ON           EMP.DEPTNO=DEPT.DEPTNO
           AND          EMP.DEPTNO IN(10,20)
           ORDER        BY  EMP.DEPTNO) IV;

   TYPE my_tab_type IS TABLE OF my_cur%ROWTYPE;

   my_tab MY_TAB_TYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN my_cur;
   FETCH my_cur BULK COLLECT INTO my_tab;
   CLOSE my_cur;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.I will go with this to implement my code @HepC

Comment: Hi its simply throwing anonymous block completed@HepC

Comment: @Nepolian That is correct. All I am doing in this code is loading the collection. You would have to implement your code to access and consume the data as needed.